# Add a missing response from Learndash API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

After playing around with the Learndash API, I realised it was not possible to get the user progression on the courses he is enrolled to. 
I contacted the Learndash support that confirmed it was not possible.

I am new to wordpress dev (I am more familiar with app development), and I would like to know how to implement this feature by myself ? Do I have, for example, to create a custom endpoint ?

I would like to know how to add some 'responses' missing for a plugin API.
What I understand, is that everything from Learndash (courses, topics etc) are like custom posts, so I am guessing it is like adding custom endpoints for posts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for the course list API. I wanted to remove the "_links" parameter from the response.
I have worked with the object-oriented concept and here is my code:

```
/* Filter sfwd-courses object */


add_filter( 'rest_prepare_sfwd-courses', array( $this, 'prepare_ld_courses' ), 999, 3 );

public function prepare_ld_courses( $response, $object, $request ) {
    
    /* Remove all links from response */
    foreach ( $response->get_links() as $k_l => $v_k ) {
        $response->remove_link( $k_l );
    }

    $data = $response->get_data();
    $base_course_id = $data['id'];
    
    $content = array( 'ID' => $course_id, 'parent_id' => (int) $base_course_id, 'title' => $course_obj->post_title, 'description' => $course_obj->post_content, 'cover_image' => null, 'thumbnail' => null);
    
    /* Set thumbnail and cover_image */
    $content = EI_Rest_Course::setup_images( $content, $base_course_id );
    
    $response->set_data( $content );
    
    return $response;

}

public static function setup_images( $content, $course_id ) {

    /* logic to get course image - $image */
    $content['thumbnail'] = $image;
    
    /* logic to get course cover_image - $cover_image */
    $content['cover_image'] = $cover_image;
    return $content;
}
```